# Cannot find symbol when using bufferwriter.readline()

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to learn java but I don't know why I'm getting there errors.What I basically want is that user will input new characters and will be written to the file as long it is not the word "stop"(program terminates at this point).

Can you guys help me?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class FileHandling{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println("Enter a File name");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String file1Name = input.next();

        if(file1Name == null){
            return;
        }

        try{
            File f1 = new File(file1Name+".txt");
            f1.createNewFile();

            String file1NameData = "";
            String content = input.next();

            FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(f1.getName(),true);
            BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);

            while(!(file1NameData=bufferWritter.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
                bufferWritter.write(file1NameData + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            bufferWritter.write(file1NameData);
            bufferWritter.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error : " );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       



    }




}
```

Comment: Please show the *exact* errors you're getting, including where they come.

Comment: But the basic problem is that you're trying to *read* from a *writer*. You can't do that - it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Are you using Java 7+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read from writer which you can't. You already have scanner and using it, you could read form System input i.e. Keyboard.

Change your line like:

From

```
while(!(file1NameData=bufferWritter.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
```

To

```
while(!(file1NameData=input.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read from your output, not your input

```
while(!input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
    bufferWritter.write(file1NameData + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("test.txt"), true))) {

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.equals("stop"))
                    break;
                writer.write(line);
                writer.newLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```